# NSDictionary - unrecognized selector sent to instance - Error

Tags: nsdictionary

I'm trying to parse JSON returned from a web service.   The response JSON looks like this   **{"API_Count":"17"}**

Here's my code.. Just trying to get the value (17).  The key value.
Here's my code..  something 'basic' must be wrong.  I get the error

```
**[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**


***Any ideas??***


NSData *jsonData = [responseObject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *err = nil;

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

for (NSDictionary *item  in json )
{
    NSObject *val = [item objectForKey:@"API_Count"];

    // ERROR !!! [NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa32b4de1b0d02c49


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

NSInteger val = [[json objectForKey:@"API_Count"] intergerValue];